# Help with the command \binom

Tags: math-mode, scaling

I want to write an expression of the form `$\binom{a}{b}$`. 
I tried with the command `\binom`, but the result is too big, and then I tried `\tbinom` but it was too small, I want to know if there is another command or another way to write that and resize it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One option that might be somewhere in the middle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\mybinom}[2]{\Bigl(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\\#2\end{array}\Bigr)}
\begin{document}
$\binom{b}{p}$ \quad
$\tbinom{b}{p}$ \quad
$\dbinom{b}{p}$ \quad
$\displaystyle\binom{b}{p}$ \quad
$\mybinom{b}{p}$
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can always scale something with the aid of [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\scalebox{<factor>}{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,graphicx}
\newcommand{\mybinom}[3][0.8]{\scalebox{#1}{$\dbinom{#2}{#3}$}}
\begin{document}
$\tbinom{b}{p}$ \quad
$\dbinom{b}{p}$ \quad
\scalebox{0.8}{$\dbinom{b}{p}$}

$\mybinom[1]{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.9]{b}{p}    \mybinom{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.7]{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.6]{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.5]{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.4]{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.3]{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.2]{b}{p}    \mybinom[0.1]{b}{p}$

\end{document}
```

Above, `\mybinom[<factor>]{<num>}{<denom>}` scales the binomial given by `\dbinom{<num>}{<denom>}` by a factor of `<factor>` (default is 80%).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i used the saclebox option, it seems the easiest an it works fine

Comment: What code represent the same formula in a (not very new version) of  word(ms)?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: MS Word should have an equation editor you can use to insert similar formulas.