# Adjust binomial bracket size to cover stuff inside

Tags: size, parenthesis

When I type a binomial like

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\binom{\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}}}{2}$

\end{document}
```

the binomial parentheses do not cover the stuff inside. Is there a way to adjust them? Since it's `\binom`, I cannot use `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: please provide a compilable example showing the problem.  there is a known (and unsolved) problem with `binom` using the stix fonts, but there shouldn't be a problem if the computer modern fonts are used, so we really must see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Just edited to add that info.

Comment: Typing the formula into https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php also yields this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with the command \binom](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109325/help-with-the-command-binom)

Comment: This posting is *not* a duplicate of [Help with the command \binom](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109325/5001). To address the issues in this posting, it's advisable to size the parentheses automatically; in contrast, the method suggested in the link utilizes fixed-size parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variation on the method suggested in [Help with the command \binom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109325/5001), with the following two modifications: (a) the round parentheses are sized automatically, and (b) the macros of the `mleftright` package are used to obtain better horizontal spacing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\newcommand{\mybinom}[2]{%
    \mleft(
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{\,}} #1\\#2 \end{array}
    \mright)}

\begin{document}

textstyle: 
$\mybinom{\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}}}{2}$ vs.\ 
$\binom{\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}}}{2}$

displaystyle:
$\displaystyle \mybinom{\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}}}{2}$ vs.\
$\displaystyle \binom{\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}}}{2}$

\end{document}
```